# Как сохранить изображение в базе данных, и как его достать обратно

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

Имеется код для отправки файла на сервер

```
handleChange(e) {
        const that = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        const url = location.pathname+location.search;
        const image = this.fileInput.current.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: reader.result
            }).then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.arrayBuffer();
                }
            }).then((buffer) => {
                var blob = new Blob(buffer, {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
                console.log(blob);
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                console.log(url);
            })
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(image)
    }
```

И его обработчик на сервере

```
const user_profile_update = (req, res) => {
    let body;
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body = Buffer.from(chunk);
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        q = User.where({login: req.query.q});
        q.updateOne({image: body}, (err, result) => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            res.status(200).send(body);
        })
    });
}
```

В БД он хранится в виде Buffer. Как мне buffer преобразовать назад в изображение? Или как сделать правильно отправку изображений на сервер

Comment: Отправляете на сервер, но храните в базе? А почему не складываете на сервер, а в базе не сохраняете название файла?

Comment: Тоесть мне не надо использовать стрим, а в body запроса записать image?

Comment: Я в голом js не силен вообще ни разу. Вам нужно сохранить файл физически на сервере, а в базу записать его название, типа `image01.jpg`

Comment: как написано выше вы на сервере сохраняете в базу имя 
только с полыным путь не сервер то есть типа htttp://serve.com/images/img.jpg  и все сразу доступен по ссылке

Comment: ну вооббще можно брать изображения из base64 строки если хоитте в базе хранить